# Confusing timestamp text

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Whenever I post a question, answer, or comment these two time stamps appear, but are confusing (like Japanese people translating instructions to English)

This is the first timestamp, "in 4 seconds":

[image: In 4 seconds timestamp]

This, "momentarily", is another timestamp I found:

[image: Momentarily timestamp]

These values should be updated to "just now" like on the questions page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.2.

As ArtOfCode correctly surmised, your phone is trapped in a localized temporal distortion field causing it to see responses from the server before they are sent... or something.

The problem is we have a single method for stringifying dates `toRelativeTime()` and this method sometimes has to shorten future dates like bounty expirations or upcoming events.  When it sees your post from the future, it assumes it's that kind of thing.

Because we can be reasonably sure that posts shown in the app have to have been posted in the past, I've changed the method to `toRelativeTimeIncludingFuture(_:Bool)` and will show "just now" for future posts, comments, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This happens in a number of places on Stack Exchange (and a number of other sites, for that matter), especially when using live-updating relational timestamps such as "just now".

It's caused by a discrepancy between your system clock and the server clock. When a comment is posted, the server records the time at which this was done, using its internal clock. That gets saved as part of the database object. When you come along, milliseconds later, to view that comment, if your system clock is behind where the server clock is, then it will show you "in X minutes" or "momentarily", etc.

An example:

- A comment is posted. The server says this happened at `2016-05-07 16:01:05.000000 UTC`.
- You come along at (absolute time) `2016-05-07 16:01:06.000000 UTC`. Your system clock is 5 seconds behind realtime, so at that point it reads `2016-05-07 16:01:01.000000`.
- The timestamp is displayed based on how long ago it was *from your system clock* (because it's done with client-side JS). Since the value the server says (16:01:05) is 4 seconds ahead of what your system clock says (16:01:01), the timestamp displays as "in 4 seconds", or "momentarily".

Comment: Why wouldn't it just say "just now" then?

Comment: @Peanut because it's *not* just now, it's in the future. Computers are literal, not approximate.

Comment: I've changed the correct answer to @BrianNickel's answer.